# Upload files even after closing the browser

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, cron

Can we set the php file upload as a background process? I mean I will select files and click upload button and then close the browser. But the process should be on the back ground and after successful completion i need to update the database as well. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate question even if the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you shut down the client, then the client will stop sending data to the server.

If you want to upload large files on a regular basis and not have the process be interrupted by people forgetting that their browser is uploading in another tab and quitting, then you might consider using a stand-alone upload tool (along the lines of [Flickr Uploadr](http://www.flickr.com/tools/uploadr/)).

Answer (score 0):

This is easily possible with *a special crafted browser* that you can close but that will not be removed from processing space until file-upload request have been finished.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit. I am wondering if it is possible.
What do you mean by "special crafted browser"?

Comment: Write the browser software your own (to spare you some time, take a browser that already exists and ships with source-code, e.g. Firefox or Chromium). This does only work for windowed applications. Those can be closed (no window visible any longer) while the process is still running. Just wanted to show that the answer is not No but Yes in a programming context.