# Resuming file upload

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, file-upload

I am writing a single page application where the user can upload photos. But I am not clear about a situation in which while user is uploading multiple photos, he closes the browser. Now when he logs in again, the browser should automatically resume the upload from the last uploading image. Is this possible? How?

1. I cannot store the image in local storage and upload since the image
   size can go beyond the local storage capacity.
2. I cannot store the file path and resume by using the file path.
   Since the browser security won't allow me to.

Comment: see the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695498/upload-files-even-after-closing-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with an SPA and the browser is closed the data in the SPA is lost. Even if you want them to resume uploading(which browser security won't allow) using the path there are 2 case scenario:
1)Does the file actually exist in the old path(No)
2)What if the user deleted or moved the file.

Anyways this should not be done using browser. Better to use a tool with 3rd party. like if you shut down the client, then the client will stop sending data to the server.

If you want to upload large files on a regular basis and not have the process be interrupted by people forgetting that their browser is uploading in another tab and quitting, then you might consider using a stand-alone upload tool (http://www.flickr.com/tools/uploadr/)

However It can be achieved by designing a special type of browser.